# Is there any block that can't be shoot through but skeletons don't know it?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I modified my mob grinder in such way that it now collects almost dead monsters in a small 2x2 area. From this area, I allow skeletons to shoot at me. As they shoot, they hit creepers and produce nice amount of music discs.

The problem is that huge portion of arrows still makes it through. I tried to reduce the damage with water, but even 3 blocks of water still aren't enough:

[image: image description]

My question therefore is: Can I make such set-up that skeletons will fire me but will never hit me?

Comment: Have you tried iron bars? I don't know or tested, just poped into my mind

Comment: Don't tripwires get activated by arrows since they're entities? You could just use those and a simple piston and block so that when the arrow goes through the tripwire it closes the small piston door.

Answer (score 3):

You could set up a small redstone contraption in order to only expose the skeleton to you if there is a creeper there.

If you want, I can make a prototype.

Also, you don't have to risk yourself: They retaliate from attacks, and snowmen attack skeletons, so they'll attack snowmen (after it attacks them)

Comment: The snowmen will die though. You can make a machine to build them !

Comment: I don't think a machine works, although I'm no expert on snowgolem-building machines. Also, if you implement my 1st suggestion with it, they wouldn't die. This is cool because this means you can set a bunch up and have _like 18 machines running at once! All the music discs!_

Comment: @Quelklef I haven't watched it, but [this video](http://www.planetminecraft.com/project/snow-golem-factory-using-redstone-and-pistons-world-download/) shows such a machine.


Maybe 18 machines would be a bit of overkill, unless you want to play music across the entire map :D

Comment: I was referring to a totally automatic machine -- this is semi; you still need to place the head

Comment: I tried snowmen before already - for some reason, the disc yield is about 10% of what I get when I'm standing there. I think they only attack snowmen *back*.

Comment: And how would you detect creeper by redstone?

Comment: [This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7Syok829qDU&feature=youtu.be) is the machine I built for this (ask if you want a build tutorial)

Comment: Oh, and you could put a hopper under the pressure plate to collect the discs.

Comment: @Quelklef I think you didn't notice that I am playing survival mode, so I can't spawn creepers using spawn eggs.

Comment: I know, you'd just fullen them into that hole. The pink section was for demonstration only.

Comment: @Quelklef This is not a solution, I can't divide skeletons from creepers. I already asked about that, you ignored that. Your **statement that skeletons attack snowmen is wrong**! Snowmen attack skeleton which retaliate. However they may as well attack other mobs resulting in the machine being stuck. Based on these remarks, I am downvoting this answer and awaiting correction.

Comment: Ah, yes, my bad. Edited about the snowmen/skeleton error. As from sorting creepers from other mobs, only two-block-tall one-block-thick one-block-wide mobs will fit into the tunnel, and take significant fall damage, likely leaving them at one skeleton arrow hit from death -- meaning it's no issue.

Comment: Man, just try it instead of theoretizing here. Snowmen do not work from reasons stated above. Apart from snowmen, your answer doesn't contain any information - it's not possible to only expose skeleton when there's a creeper without sorting skeletons from creepers.

Comment: Yes, but, as I said, that doesn't matter -- just kill the skeleton, too, since it'll be at one hit from your shooter skeleton. As for the snowmen, the skeleton will try attacking them -- just get the snowmen to attack them once.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think skeletons can see through anything. Only spiders can. But you can toughen up your mob grinder with slabs, that may stop skeletons from shooting at **you** but at the creepers and other mobs.

Answer (score 1):

Simply don't stand there. Make a Iron golem the other side. Skeleton would try to hit it. but it will rarely hit it. Iron golems are cheap to make. 4 iron blocks and a pumpkin.